# Why choose frozen hydrogen for proton spin polarization testing?

Tags: protons

Is frozen hydrogen particularly good for polarizing proton spin?  Or are other elements particularly bad?   It takes quite an effort to reach the near absolute zero necessary to freeze hydrogen.  See this paper [frozen hydrogen](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06834)

Comment: Hydrogen is protons.   Anything other elements have neutrons to complicate them.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow Would neutrons inhibit the protons from polarizing?  Why?